# Artifactory version search with Generic repo using simple-default layout

Tags: artifactory

As title says, I have a Generic repo using the simple-default layout.  I'm trying to use [Artifact Version Search (/api/search/versions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactVersionSearch) and Artifact Latest Version Search (/api/search/latestVersion).

The repo works and the simple-default layout is able to parse artifact path+names fine, see below. We have a valid Artifactory Pro license. I've tried this with the token for a "reader" user and also with my admin-privileged token.

[image]
[image]

When I try using `g=<something>&a=udpu_client` for groupId and artifactId, the API returns a 400 "The groupId and artifactId cannot be empty". This isn't a Maven repo and so I don't really know what groupId is supposed to be. The docs have been absolutely useless on this matter. I've tried combinations of `udpu-local`, `udpu_client`, as well as tossing `org` in there, replacing dashes and underscores for dots, and many others, but the API only ever returns "The groupId and artifactId cannot be empty".

Please, can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?